# Python remote program execution non-blocking

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have a web application where the user can issue the request to execute a program on a different machine. The web application is written in Python. The remote program is C, but on this side language shouldn't matter.

So SSH is the way to go I think (which has been answered here before). But in my use case the remote program can run for days, and obviously I don't want the ssh call to block my web application.

So I could run the remote program as a background process. But I am also interested in knowing when the program finishes and in the exit code.

So is there any way in achieving this?

Comment: Seems like you need to start a daemon over ssh. If you don't want to start a system service on the remote host (you probably don't), screen/dtach/tmux are the way to go. Take a look at screen, which is a nice linux utility for detaching sessions and then launch it via ssh.

Comment: Thanks, screen looks promising. At least for the nin-blocking part of my question. But how about connecting to stdout/stderr? As far as I understand screen, there is no way of getting notified if the remote program finished or crashed apart from starting a new ssh session, connectint to the screen process and reattaching the window.

Comment: The only two ways to get notified when a remote program terminates is to (a) keep checking/polling/maintain open SSH connection or (b) have the remote host notify you, but that requires you host to expose some endpoint, which comes dangerously close to full blown asynchronous microservices. I'd suggest to wrap the remote program with some small script that saves stdout/stderr/retcode to some files, and then periodically check for their existence.